# Cabal build all failing with error: Symbol not found: _sodium_free

Tags: cardano-node, build

Attempting to build the cardano-node on Mac OS Big Sur while following the instructions found here: https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/installing-cardano-node/#macos

When I hit the `cabal build all` step I'm given the following error:

```
[ 14 of 193] Compiling PlutusCore.Pretty.Readable ( plutus-core/src/PlutusCore/Pretty/Readable.hs, dist/build/PlutusCore/Pretty/Readable.o, dist/build/PlutusCore/Pretty/Readable.dyn_o )
<command line>: dlopen(/Users/sanfordleach/.cabal/store/ghc-8.10.4/lib/libHScrdn-crypt-clss-2.0.0-a62d56db-ghc8.10.4.dylib, 5): Symbol not found: _sodium_free
  Referenced from: /Users/sanfordleach/.cabal/store/ghc-8.10.4/lib/libHScrdn-crypt-clss-2.0.0-a62d56db-ghc8.10.4.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/sanfordleach/.cabal/store/ghc-8.10.4/lib/libHScrdn-crypt-clss-2.0.0-a62d56db-ghc8.10.4.dylib
```

[image]

Note: I have the environmental vars.  Not sure how to check that libsodium is installed correctly but I ran the steps in the instructions.

Please help? Thank you!

EDIT 1: I see the libsodium files in my `/usr/local/lib` so I believe it's installed correctly

EDIT 2: At this point I've already created a node on an Ubuntu instance and it's working fine... not sure if its an issue with Mac OS but I recommend doing the same if you run into this issue.

Comment: Do you have a libsodium.so file in your $LD_LIBRARY_PATH (/usr/local/lib)?

Comment: I don't believe I do... is that something that's supposed to happen on the install?

Comment: I see ```libsodium.23.dylib, libsodium.dylib,  libsodium.a, libsodium.la``` in my ```/usr/local/lib``` but not ```libsodium.so```....

```libsodium.pc``` is present in my pkgconfig

Comment: @sandy-leach did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2):

I was running into this problem on MacOS Monterey (M1 Pro) while building [plutus-starter](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-starter).

Just like OP, I seemed to have installed libsodium correctly as I had all the libs in my PATH. Then I stumbled upon this [thread](https://forum.cardano.org/t/trying-to-build-a-cardano-node-cli-arm64v8-docker-image/41370/6) that solved it for me. What I needed was to add a `cabal.project.local` file in the root of my project with

```
package cardano-crypto-praos
  flags: -external-libsodium-vrf
```

which I think makes the [VRF not be bundled](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-base/blob/master/cardano-crypto-praos/cardano-crypto-praos.cabal#L42), and thus ignored as we can do without it anyway.

Also, before that, I rebuilt using libsodium-1.0.18-stable.tar.gz from https://download.libsodium.org/libsodium/releases/, which may also have helped.

Perhaps all of that is useful to someone!

Comment: I'm having the same issue but sadly this solution didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

If libsodium.so file is missing from /usr/local/lib, the problem here is that libsodium is not correctly installed on your Mac OS X environment.

Answer (score 0):

Did you compile and install libsodium?
Did you check environment variable to see that this is added?

Comment: Yep, env vars are there and I ran all of the steps to run libsodium that are in the instructions

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to run the leader logs script, which happens to depend on `libsodium`. I run on OSX and this problem has had me dweling on the same questions many asked above.

If you are using OS, you should use the `.dylib` files as reference. I've found a few open source examples that opted for a best effor library detection mechanism (see https://github.com/papacarp/pooltool.io/blob/master/leaderLogs/leaderLogs.py#L109), which points to using `libsodium.23.dylib` for OSX.

Unfortunately, I  had an additional problem before being able to run the leaders log. I installed `libsodium` with `brew`, which installed the official libsodium project, but the code I needed to run required extra APIs that are only in the IOHK version of the library, so once I downloaded, compiled and installed the source code from this version, everything worked like a charm.

So, a couple of things:

1. Make sure your configs point to the appropriate path of libdsodium (in OSX `/usr/local/lib/libsodium.23.dylib`).
2. Depending on the version you had compiled and installed you might be missing APIs/functions. Check you have the correct version of the library.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).