# Plutus Pioneer Cohort 3, Mac M1 cabal build error: Failed to build small-steps-test-0.1.0.0. , symbol not found in flat namespace '_sodium_free'

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, cabal, nix-shell

I'm using MacOS Monterey with M1 chip, and trying to build `plutus-app` using Nix

Entering `$ nix-shell` using the specified tag from week01 is working fine, hence I can enter into the shell. The problem starts when I run `$ cabal build` inside `plutus-pioneer-program/code/week01`

I'm encountering this issue where it seems like `libsodium` isn't installed correctly.

Installation guide I follow: https://github.com/renzwo/cardano-plutus-apps-install-m1

This solution isn't working for me either, or rather, because of different topic (it discussed about `plutus-starter`, whereas this is for Plutus Pioneer 3): [Cabal build all failing with error: Symbol not found: _sodium_free](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/4198/cabal-build-all-failing-with-error-symbol-not-found-sodium-free)

Additional info:

- running `nix-shell` in specified tag commit for week01
- running `nix-shell` no problem with IOHK binary cache already specified in nix.conf
- I've reinstalled nix and tried it again, but it still give me the same result.

I'm stuck here, and don't have any other machine to spin up Ubuntu at the moment.

[image]